# Websphere 8 JNDI lookup of local EJB object

Tags: ejb, websphere, jndi

I'm trying to call EJB3 Service Bean Local Interface using the JNDI lookup
and the sample code is like this

localInterfaceObj = (Object) initialContext.lookup("ejblocal:com.infopro.eswx.service.ejb.NdcServiceControllerSBLocal")

but i get error

[10/29/13 16:08:59:609 GMT+08:00] 00000028 SystemErr     R javax.naming.ConfigurationException: NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: ejblocal
[10/29/13 16:08:59:609 GMT+08:00] 00000028 SystemErr     R  at com.infopro.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.getLocalInterface(ServiceLocator.java:257)
[10/29/13 16:08:59:609 GMT+08:00] 00000028 SystemErr     R  at com.infopro.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.getLocalInterface(ServiceLocator.java:273)

i've also tried other string inside the lookup() method in the form of
ejblocal:#
which is 
ejblocal:ESERV/ESWX302EJB_NDC.jar/NdcServiceControllerSB#com.infopro.eswx.service.ejb.NdcServiceControllerSBLocal
and ejblocal:ESERV/ESWX302EJB_NDC/NdcServiceControllerSB#com.infopro.eswx.service.ejb.NdcServiceControllerSBLocal

and ejb/com.infopro.eswx.service.ejb.NdcServiceControllerSBLocal

but still encounter the same error

is there any way to solve this?
thank you.

regards,
Tan

Comment: What does your creation of InitialContext() look like?  The ejblocal namespace should always be available.

Comment: quite a normal one                                                       import javax.naming.InitialContext;                               private InitialContext initialContext = null;

Comment: Are you passing properties to the `new InitialContext(...)` constructor that would interfere with the default factories?

Comment: yes, the property in InitialContext() ... i found out it is due to the value defined at javax.naming.Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES was not correct.initially i use com.ibm.ws.naming ... we need to define both com.ibm.ws.runtime:com.ibm.ws.naming

Comment: Why are you specifying that property at all?  Why not just use `new InitialContext()` with no properties specified at all?